# How i can print Arrays with for each loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php

    $students = array(      
        "student1" => array(
            "age" => 36,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "Master",
        ),
        "student2" => array(
            "age" => 25,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "BA",
        ),
        "student3" => array(
            "age" => 26,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "BA",
        ),
        "student4" => array(
            "age" => 25,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "BA",
        ),
        "student5" => array(
            "age" => 20,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "Master",
        ),
        "student6" => array(
            "age" => 20,
            "gender" => "male",
            "qualification" => "F.A",
        ),
    );

    ?>
```

And i need result like this.

```
Hello Student1
Your age is 36 and
Your gender is male and
Your qualification is Master.

Hello Student2
Your age is 25 and
Your gender is male and
Your qualification is BA.
```

I have try like this.

```
foreach($students as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "Mr".$key."<br />";
        foreach($value as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo" Your  $key  is  $value  and <br />";

    }
}
```

And my result like this.

```
Hello Student1
Your age is 36 and
Your gender is male and
Your qualification is Master and

Hello Student2
Your age is 25 and
Your gender is male and
Your qualification is BA and
```

Comment: Ur expected answer and ur result is same !! so whats ur question ??

Answer (score 1):

No need for that other foreach inside, you can just use one. Each copy of the sub array (`$info`), you will just have to call its indices.

```
foreach ($students as $name => $info) {
    echo "
    Hello $name, <br/>
    Your age is: $info[age] <br/>
    Your gender is: $info[gender] <br/>
    Your qualification is: $info[qualification] <hr/> 
    ";
}
```

But if you really want to go that two foreach route, yes you could add a condition in the second loop to prevent it from adding the superfluous `and`:

```
foreach ($students as $name => $info) {
    echo "Hello $name ";
    foreach($info as $att => $val) {
        echo "Your $att is: $val ", (end($info) != $val) ? ' and ' : '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
foreach($students as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "Mr".$key."";
    $count = 1;
    foreach($value as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo" Your  $key  is  $val";
        if ($count != count($val)) {
            echo " and ";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach($students as $key => $value) {
   echo 'Hello ', $key, '  Your age is ', $value['age'], ' gender is ' . $value['gender'], ' and Your qualification is ', $value['qualification']
}
```

You can concat string with `echo`, but coma will be better for performance.